# Matrix Multiplication Verification

Tags: matrix-multiplication

This question relates to the 2nd edition of *Probability and Computation* by Mitzenmacher and Upfal.

[image]

[image]

The authors then use the Law of Total Probability
[image]

My question concerns the line that begins with $\leq$. Shouldn't that be replaced with $=$ because the authors proved that the event $\mathbf{AB}    \bar{r} =    \mathbf{C}\bar{r}$ is equivalent to the event $$r_{1} = - \frac{\sum_{j=2}^n d_{1j} r_{j}}{d_{11}}$$ ?

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).

Comment: The authors do not say that $AB\bar{r} = C\bar{r}$ is *equivalent* to the event $r_1 = -\sum_j d_{1j}r_j / d_{11}$, rather that it implies it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that all matrices in question are $n \times n$.

Suppose that $A=B=0$ are zero matrices and $C=I$ is the identity matrix. Then
$$ \Pr[ABr = Cr] = \Pr[r = 0] = 2^{-n}. $$